# Getting weird string lengths from C string

Tags: c++, c-strings

I am attempting to extract words from a c string and then compare then with the words in a 2d array and count the number of matching words. I've noticed that some of the string lengths are not what I was expecting and that's probably why numMatches isn't correct but I'm not sure why I'm getting string lengths that don't match. Where am I going wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string.h>


int main ()
{
    char str[] ="bob amy ted susan";
    char * pch;
    pch = strtok (str," ");
    char arr[4][10] = {"bob", "amy", "susan", "ted"};
    int numMatches = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        cout<< pch <<endl;
        cout << strlen(arr[i]) << endl;
        if (strcmp(pch,arr[i])==0){
            numMatches++;
        }
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
        i++;



    }
    cout << arr[2] << endl;
    cout << numMatches << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

```
Output I'm getting...

bob
3
amy
3
ted
5
susan
3
Total Matches : 2

Output I'm expecting...
bob
3
amy
3
ted
3
susan
5
Total Matches : 4
```

Comment: Please post the output your program outputs and post what output did you expect or wanted to have.

Comment: What is the output you're getting? What output did you expect? Please [edit] your question to include that. Also please learn how to use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values, that's how you usually figure out problems like these.

Comment: *Where am I going wrong here?* -- Not using `std::stringstream` to parse, and not using `std::unordered_set<std::string>` to store the words to search.

Comment: Typo: "susan" and "ted" are reversed in the array. So you are printing the length of the wrong strings. Or maybe you meant to reverse them. Either way, the lengths are different.

Comment: Much can be learned by printing out `arr[i]` along with its size.

Comment: @JesperJuhl In what universe is `cout << strlen(arr[i]) << endl;` "C, no questions asked"

Comment: Please add the expected and actual output and note that you print `pch`, but then the length of `arr[i]`. Maybe your expectations are wrong here. Btw. you tagged this C++, any reason you don't use `std::string`?

Comment: [See a more C++ way of doing this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3297b6345f7353d).

Comment: "not reproducible" yes it definitively is ... "caused by typos" ... depends a lot on OP's intent; if they want to match the order then yes, it's two words switched, if they want to **count** (`numMatches`...) matches however then it's definitively not a "typo".  Leaving it closed because it's probably of not much use to anyone except OP who already has my answer, though.

Comment: @OP Regardless of the language, this is a very bad way for searching if a name is in a list.  What if there were thousands of names in the name list?  For each name you are searching for, you have to start back at the beginning of the name list.

Answer (score 1):

Go step by step through your code, and "execute" it in your head / on paper:

```
First iteration:
i == 0
pch == "bob"
arr[i] == arr[0] == "bob"
strlen("bob") == 3
numMatches increased to 1

Second iteration:
i == 1
pch == "amy"
arr[i] == arr[1] == "amy"
strlen("amy") == 3
numMatches increased to 2

Third iteration:
i == 2
pch == "ted"
arr[i] == arr[2] == "susan"
strlen("susan") == 5
numMatches NOT increased, stays at 2

Forth iteration:
i == 3
pch == "susan"
arr[i] == arr[3] == "ted"
strlen("ted") == 3
numMatches NOT increased, stays at 2

Done, pch == NULL
```

As you see, you're comparing the token (`pch`) to just one single value of your `arr`.  You probably want a second loop there which loops over `arr[i]` for all possible values of `i`.  Ideally you should put this loop into its own function, name suggestion `isInArr` (or `matches` or ... depends a lot on what this is actually supposed to become in the the end :) )

---

*Some more suggestions:*

- `using namespace std;` [Don't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1116364).
- `#include <string.h>` This is for C, when including a C header in C++, use `#include <cstring>`
- If the purpose of this code is not to learn about C strings and `strtok`, then better use more C++ idiomatic code, e.g. `std::stringstream` ([example from PaulMcKenzie](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3297b6345f7353d) in case the comment get's lost)

Comment: *You probably want a second loop there.* I think the problem is one of typo. The OP probably didn't mean to use "ted" and "susan" in mismatching order it the two lines.

Comment: @RSahu Hm, OP is counting matches though, would suggest to me that the order is irrelevant.

Comment: Only the OP knows what their intent was.